# How can I Move to next viewController by clicking ActionSheet Buttons in Storyboard in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

I am developing an application in that i need one requirement that is when I click on ActionSheet buttons I want go to nextviewcontroller.I tried with fallowing code but it wouldnot go to next viewcontroller.how can i connect segues in storybord.can any one help me.thanks inadvance...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"



@interface Tab2ViewController : UIViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate>
{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
    SecondViewController *secondViewController;
}
@end



#import "Tab2ViewController.h"

@interface Tab2ViewController ()

@end

@implementation Tab2ViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(60.0f, 180.0f, 200.0f,70.0f);
    [button setTitle:@"Show Action Sheet" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];



}

- (void)showActionSheet:(id)sender
{
     NSString *actionSheetTitle = @"Action Sheet Demo"; //Action Sheet Title
     NSString *destructiveTitle = @"Destructive Button"; //Action Sheet Button Titles
     NSString *other1 = @"Other Button 1";
     NSString *other2 = @"Other Button 2";
     NSString *other3 = @"Other Button 3";
     NSString *cancelTitle = @"Cancel Button";
     UIActionSheet *actionSheet1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:actionSheetTitle delegate:self
     cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveTitle
     otherButtonTitles:other1, other2, other3, nil];
      actionSheet1.actionSheetStyle=UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
     [actionSheet1 showInView:self.view];


}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue1");
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"third"])
    {
         NSLog(@"prepareForSegue2");
        secondViewController=[segue destinationViewController];       

    }
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet1 clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //Get the name of the current pressed button
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet1 buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if  ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Destructive Button"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Destructive pressed --> Delete Something");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"third" sender:nil];
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Other 1 pressed");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"third" sender:nil];
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 2"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Other 2 pressed");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"third" sender:nil];
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 3"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Other 3 pressed");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"third" sender:nil];
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Cancel Button"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel pressed --> Cancel ActionSheet");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"third" sender:nil];
    }

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open new Viewcontroller then try with below line hope it helps you:

```
   UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   Synergy *objSynergy = (Synergy *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Synergy"];
  [self presentModalViewController:objSynergy animated:YES];
```

Synergy is my new controller name you replace it with your class name change this code according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me::

```
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 1"]) {

    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    Paypal_ViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Paypal_ViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```